# call require permission which may be rejected by user

Tags: android, location

i need get location in android....
i write this code :

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    !=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Comment...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},1);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //Call whatever you want
                myPermissionNeededMethod();
            }
        }

    });
}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode){
        case 1: {
            if((grantResults.length>0) && grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                myPermissionNeededMethod();
            else{
                // the user deny to giving permission so we ask him again or whatever we need to do !
            }
            return;

        }
    }
}
```

in myPermissionNeededMethod() i write:

```
    public  void  myPermissionNeededMethod(){
    LocationManager locationManager =  (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Location location= locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

}
```

but again i recieved error call require permission which may be rejected by user ....!!!!
if me can not use  myPermissionNeededMethod() method me should be copy code in else section in oncreate and onRequestPermissionsResult ....!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not an error. It is a Lint warning. Lint cannot tell that the only places where you are calling `myPermissionNeededMethod()` are checking to see that you have this permission.

Making this method `private` may help.

Otherwise, put your text cursor somewhere in the code that is giving you the warning (i.e., has the red or yellow undersquiggle), press <kbd>Alt-Enter</kbd>, and look for a quick-fix that adds a `@SuppressLint` annotation, to tell Lint to stop complaining about this issue. Then, it is up to you to make sure that you only call `myPermissionNeededMethod()` when you are sure that you already hold this permission.